# why the page auto reload and auto get empty date when I click a button on laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, click

URL http://localhost:8000/upload

```
 $('button[name="postname"]').click(function(){
      var img_route=$(".template").attr("href");
      if(typeof img_route ==='undefined'|| img_route === null){
            alert('Please upload image') 
        }else{
            var checkresult=checktable();
            if( checkresult == 1){
                document.formpost.action="postNews";
                document.formpost.method="post"; 
                document.formpost.submit(); 
            }
        }
    });


function checktable(){
    if($(".table").val()==''){  
      return 0;
    }else{
      return 1;  
    }
}
```

blade view

```
<form action="" method=""  name="formpost"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  role="form"  class="form-inline">
           {{ csrf_field() }}
.......  
<button type="button" name="postname" >Post News</button>
</form>
```

when I click the button
no input the image
go to the

```
if(typeof img_route ==='undefined'|| img_route === null)
```

or

```
checktable()   return 0;
```

the page will autoreload and 
the URL column

will show

```
http://localhost:8000/upload?tablename=&img=&imgroute=&....
```

auto use the get method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page auto reload could be not specified the button type(which fallback to default "submit").

Its not autoreload actually, but it redirect to the action you specified inside form `action` attribute which redirect to the same page:

Try this:

```
<button type="button" name="postname">Post News</button>
```

or let the js code cover it for you:

```
$('button[name="postname"]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // add this
  .........
});
```